# How to open personal.xlsb and run macros automatically on all open excel and csv files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three files that open automatically each morning:
One is my "master" excel file that contains all our inventory SKUs, showing pricing, stock levels, etc. The other two are auto-generated CSV files (one pulls pricing from our POS system that is updated by our purchasing people; the other pulls stock levels from same POS system).

The "master" file uses formulas (mostly index/match) to update each SKU for pricing and stock levels. There are additional formulas based on stock levels to indicate whether the SKU should appear on our website.

In order for the "master" file to update correctly, I have to delete all spaces from Columns C:E in one CSV file and delete all spaces from Column F in the second CSV file.

I created macros in personal.xlsb workbook (one for deleting spaces in C:E and one for deleting spaces in F). How can I get these to run automatically when the files open each morning?

Comment: Just call it from the [`Workbook_Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) event?

Comment: Some thing like this should serve your purpose `Sub Button1_Click()  
    
    call Deletespace1  
    Worksheets(1).calculate ' calculate if required
    call Deletespace2
    Worksheets(1).calculate ' calculate if required
   
  
msgbox "Done"  
  
end sub` As suggested by Comintern, it can be integrated with `Workbook_Open` event

Comment: You'll need to set up an event handler to catch the workbook_open event of
the Excel application object.

Chip Pearson has an excellent introduction to this:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: You can use Workbook_Open() method or Auto_Open() method to do your task as referred in https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/